# Applying Sqlfilter to ServiceBus topic trigger in Azure Function?

Tags: function, azure, servicebus

So we have a Azure ServiceBus topic triggering a Azure Function. Problem is we need to apply a filter on the subscription. Json looks like this:

```
"bindings": [
{
  "name": "mySbMsg",
  "type": "serviceBusTrigger",
  "direction": "in",
  "topicName": "testtopic",
  "subscriptionName": "AllMessages",
  "connection": "RootManageSharedAccessKey",
  "accessRights": "Manage"
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> we have a Azure ServiceBus topic triggering a Azure Function. Problem is we need to apply a filter on the subscription.

As far as I know, Azure Functions do not provide a direct way to set up filters for an existing subscription while defining the function bindings and other configuration settings in function.json. If you’d like to apply filters for subscriptions, you could set up filters when you create subscriptions. For more information about creating subscriptions with filters, please refer to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions#create-a-subscription).

Comment: As far as I can see, the link to the documentation provides absolutely no instructions on creating a subscription with filters

Comment: It seems that with .Net Standard, there's no programmatic way in C# to create the filter, like there was using the old .Net Framework.  It appears now that it's a provisioning thing.  Here's a link to the .Net Standard samples for ServiceBus:  https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/tree/master/samples/DotNet/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/TopicFilters

Comment: Also it appears you can do it with PowerShell - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.servicebus/New-AzureRmServiceBusRule?view=azurermps-6.13.0

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new subscriber with filter `using Microsoft.ServiceBus;` inside some temporary application (some cloud service or even console application).
When the new subscriber is subscribed, kill it.

Then use the same subscription name in your Function, the events will be filtered.

Answer (score 0):

WindowsAzure.ServiceBus.5.0.0 library, which provides you to create filters for the subscription which is already present.

Alternatively, you can go with tools like Serverless360, Here this will have an option to create filters for Topic Subscriptions.

Refer this [blog](https://www.serverless360.com/blog/manage-azure-topic-subscription-rules) for more details.